# Would Join on PairRDD's result in co-locating data by keys?

Tags: apache-spark

I wanted to understand how the join on two pair rdd's work? Would it result in shuffling data from both the RDD's with same key into same partition? If that is the case would it be better to use partitionBy function to partition (by the join attribute) the RDD at creation for lesser shuffling?

Thanks
Ankur

Answer (score 2):

short answer: yes and yes

At least 1 RDD needs to be shuffled. If the partitioning of the base RDD is known, only the joined RDD will be shuffled. Otherwise both RDDs will be shuffled sothat matching keys fall in the same partition.

Comment: @Ankur there's a good read on this specific point in the freely available content of 'Learning Spark' : https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/learning-spark/9781449359034/ch04.html

Comment: Thanks a lot maasg, this really helps and the book also outlines it very well.